Send jpeg images as mjpeg through RTSP - gStreamer
I'm trying to create an ip camera emulator. I use gstreamer rtsp server https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c for that but I have some issues with pipeline. Now my command looks like this:
/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-launch multifilesrc location='./%d.jpeg' index=1 caps='image/jpeg,framerate=12/1' loop=true ! jpegparse ! rtpjpegpay name=pay0 pt=96

And it doesn't work. I understand that before rtpjpegpay should have had more parameters but I lack the experience.

/gst-rtsp-server/examples/test-launch multifilesrc location=./%d.jpeg index=1 loop=true ! image/jpeg,width=1280,height=1024,framerate=12/1 ! jpegdec ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay name=pay0


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
